# MySQL, Optimizing Subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

Strugle with optimizing this subquery that count item:

```
SELECT @crewid:=crewid AS `crewid`, COUNT(id) AS `number_documents`,
        (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tblScan WHERE classification IS NOT NULL AND crewId = @crewid) AS `classified`,
        (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM tblScan WHERE classification IS NULL AND crewId = @crewid) AS `unclassified`,
        (SELECT CONCAT(name, ' ', surname) FROM tblcrew WHERE crewId = @crewid) AS `crewname`,
        (SELECT uploadeddate FROM tblScan WHERE crewid = @crewid ORDER BY uploadeddate DESC LIMIT 0,1) AS `uploadeddate`,
        (SELECT uploadedby FROM tblScan WHERE crewid = @crewid ORDER BY uploadedby DESC LIMIT 0,1) AS `uploadedby`,
        (SELECT updateddate FROM tblScan WHERE crewid = @crewid AND updateddate IS NOT NULL ORDER BY updateddate DESC LIMIT 0,1) AS `updateddate`,
        (SELECT updatedby FROM tblScan WHERE crewid = @crewid AND updatedby IS NOT NULL ORDER BY updatedby DESC LIMIT 0,1) AS `updatedby`
        FROM tblScan
```

Hope someone could help

Thanks,
Dels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
   `tblScan`.`crewId` AS `crewid`
   COUNT(`tblScan`.`id`) AS `number_documents`,
   SUM(IF(`tblScan`.`classification` IS NOT NULL,1,0)) AS `classified`,
   SUM(IF(`tblScan`.`classification` IS NULL,1,0)) AS `unclassified`,
   CONCAT(`tblcrew`.`name`, ' ', `tblcrew`.`surname`) AS `crewname`,
   MAX(`tblScan`.`uploadeddate`) AS `uploadeddate`,
   MAX(`tblScan`.`uploadedby`) AS `uploadedby`,
   MAX(IFNULL(`tblScan`.`updateddate`,'0000-01-01')) AS `updateddate`,
   MAX(IFNULL(`tblScan`.`updatedby`,'0')) AS `updatedby`
FROM tblScan
INNER JOIN tblcrew ON `tblcrew`.`crewId`=`tblScan`.`crewId`
GROUP BY `tblScan`.`crewId`
```

Comment: __SUM(IF(`tblScan`.`classification` IS NOT NULL,1,0)) AS `classified`__ can also be written as __count(`tblScan`.`classification`)__ as it will only return the count of non-NULL values. check [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-null.html)

Comment: @husbas Yes it can. My code was meant to be instructive, not productive - from the OQ I got the impression, the OP can optimize quite a lot of his queries by understanding the principle.